# Swiper Circle progress bar

Tags: javascript, css, swiper.js

could you help me with creating rounded progress bar with Swiper? I tried but all my tries didn't worked out.

Here is my js

```
const swiper_news = new Swiper('.slider-news', {
        spaceBetween: 30,
        pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-pagination',
            
        type: "custom"
        }
    });
```

and here is my css:

```
.swiper-pagination.swiper-pagination-progressbar-fill{
        border-radius:20px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

- I don't know you are checked `swiper` docs or not but anyway it's not for progress bar it's for swipe you can check any tutorial for how to create a progress bar because there's many ways and the way depending on what you are trying to do so what i want to say is just forget about swiper it's not for that

Comment: Well, I've got a slider (Swiper) and it has a couple of slides. I could use dots/bullets for navigation and set the autoplay. Also I could use progress bar and Swiper has such one and I do. But the issue is that it is a straight line, but I need a circle. I know that I can use custom slide for such purposes with that lib, but I tried and It didn't worket out.